# Generating Multiple Duplicate Objects

Tags: python, class, object

I'm trying to generate multiple class objects using this code:

```
for playerNum in xrange(players):             # Players is usually between 2-8.
    vars["player"+str(playerNum)] = Player()  # Player() is a class.
```

I realize that this is a terrible way to do it, so what could I do instead of this? The only thing that they will be assigned to is the class Player.

Comment: Seems fine I suppose since you want to make a dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put them in a list or a dictionary.

```
player_list = [Player() for _ in xrange(players)]
```

or

```
player_dict = {'player%s' % i : Player() for i in xrange(players)}
```

Comment: It's part of a function, so is there another way to make it global without putting in "global player_list" ?

Comment: Why do you want to make it global at all? That's rarely a good idea. Just return it from the function.